# iOS Notification Trigger: fortnightly and/or quarterly

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, calendar

I can't seem to find any Apple Documentation for this exact scenario, and I've tried various ways to do this and I keep coming up empty.

I would like to schedule a repeating notification (`iOS 10+` so `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` or equivalent).
These are *Local Notifications* **not** Push Notifications.

#### My Goal:

Schedule notifications that repeat:

- *once a fortnight* (e.g., every **second** Tuesday)
- *once a quarter* (e.g., 1st of **every 3 months**)

#### My Current Approach:

These triggers work well, and are simple to implement (Running the code in a Swift Playground).

```js
// Every day at 12pm
var daily = DateComponents()
daily.hour = 12
let dailyTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: daily, repeats: true)
dailyTrigger.nextTriggerDate() // "Jan 4, 2017, 12:00 PM"

// Every Tuesday at 12pm
var weekly = DateComponents()
weekly.hour = 12
weekly.weekday = 3
let weeklyTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: weekly, repeats: true)
weeklyTrigger.nextTriggerDate() // "Jan 10, 2017, 12:00 PM"

// The 1st of every month at 12pm
var monthly = DateComponents()
monthly.hour = 12
monthly.day = 1
let monthlyTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: monthly, repeats: true)
monthlyTrigger.nextTriggerDate() // "Feb 1, 2017, 12:00 PM"

// Every 1st of February at 12pm
var yearly = DateComponents()
yearly.hour = 12
yearly.day = 1
yearly.month = 2
let yearlyTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: yearly, repeats: true)
yearlyTrigger.nextTriggerDate() // "Feb 1, 2017, 12:00 PM"
```

#### But...

I can't seem to get a `fortnightly` or `quarterly` trigger to function correctly.

```js
// Every second Tuesday at 12pm
// ... There is no "date.fortnight", is this possible?

// The 1st of every quarter at 12pm
var quarterly = DateComponents()
quarterly.hour = 12
quarterly.day = 4
// Values: 1, 2, 3 or 4 all produce the same "nextTriggerDate" - why?
quarterly.quarter = 4 
let quarterlyTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: quarterly, repeats: true)
quarterlyTrigger.nextTriggerDate()
```

So, to be clear, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to get a notification that repeats every fortnight?
2. How do we get a trigger for once a quarter?

Since `DateComponents()` has a `quarter` unit, I assume that a `quarterly` trigger is possible. For the fortnightly reminder however, I'm not even sure if this is possible...

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Do we have an answer for the quarter trigger yet?

Answer (score 8):

I didn't see any direct option to trigger fortnight notification.Suggestion from my end.

**1)** *Is it possible to get a notification that repeats every fortnight?*

I am proposing two options:

1. Can we use `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` to repeat the notification with a time interval of two weeks time? Example below

   ```
   let timeInterValFor2Weeks = 1190507.790425003

   let intervalTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: timeInterValFor2Weeks, repeats: true)//"Jan 3, 2017, 5:24 PM"

   intervalTrigger.nextTriggerDate() //"Jan 17, 2017, 12:05 PM"
   ```
2. Schedule two `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` trigger, which should  trigger first and third day of a month. For example it should fire notification in first Sunday and third Sunday of a month.

   ```
   var fortnightPart1 = DateComponents()
   fortnightPart1.weekday = 1 //(Day..here Sunday)
   fortnightPart1.weekdayOrdinal = 2 //= n == (nth Day in the month...here 2nd Sunday in every month month)
   fortnightPart1.hour = 12

   let fortnightTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: fortnightPart1, repeats: true)
   fortnightPart1.nextTriggerDate()
   ```

**2)** *How do we get a trigger for once a quarter?*

If there is no direct option available, then I suggest the same solution as above.

Comment: Gave you the bounty since you were the only one who bothered to reply: thanks!
I think I'm just going to use `EventKit` and make calendar events rather than notifications. It's a little more flexible.

Comment: My local notification was not working. It took me 2 days to figure out just one silly mistake instead of using WEEKDAY in date component, I used DAY.