# iOS 10: repeating local user notification from specific date every month

Tags: swift, ios10

The notification will be triggered in i.e 25-7-2017 using: `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dueDate , repeats: false)`

How can I repeat the notification every month i.e 25-8-2017, 25-9-2017 and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Notification Trigger: fortnightly and/or quarterly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441124/ios-notification-trigger-fortnightly-and-or-quarterly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of providing a full date when you initialize the trigger, pass a set of `DateComponents` containing only the day of the month, and set `repeats` to `true`.

```
let components = DateComponents(day: 25)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
```