# Repeating local notifications for specific days of week after certain start date, like after 7 days?

Tags: swift, notifications

I want to schedule notification for specific days of the week, repeating, but want it to start after 7 days.

Currently, I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061324/repeating-local-notifications-for-specific-days-of-week-swift-3-ios-10), where I can schedule but starts from now. I am looking for a start date for this? How Can I achieve this?

```swift
 //Create Date from picker selected value.
    func createDate(weekday: Int, hour: Int, minute: Int, year: Int)->Date{

        var components = DateComponents()
        components.hour = hour
        components.minute = minute
        components.year = year
        components.weekday = weekday // sunday = 1 ... saturday = 7
        components.timeZone = .current

        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        return calendar.date(from: components)!
    }

    //Schedule Notification with weekly bases.
    func scheduleNotification(at date: Date, body: String, titles:String) {

        let triggerWeekly = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,.hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerWeekly, repeats: true)

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = titles
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.categoryIdentifier = "todoList"

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Uh oh! We had an error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Can have look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441124/ios-notification-trigger-fortnightly-and-or-quarterly) answer as well.